# Use javascript to keep button state down and do another task

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two buttons on my page, I want it so that one starts in the down state display a piece of text in a div, then if the other button is pressed that button stays in the downstate displaying its piece of text in a div and making the first button in the normal state and hiding it's piece of text.

This is the sort of code I have been unsuccessfully working with;

```
$('#myButton').on('mousedown', function () {
    $('#myButton').toggleClass('myButtonActivated',0);
    document.getElementById('info1').style.zIndex = 1;
    document.getElementById('info2').style.zIndex = 0;
})
```

Any guidance would be great, thanks.

Comment: You should share your HTML markup and maybe provide a jsFiddle

Comment: In the description you mention two buttons, but in the code we can see reference to only one button (`#myButton`). Can you give more information about the second one?

Comment: @mabedan The second button is just myButton1. I simply have 4 elements on the page 2 buttons black text/white background in normal, and vice versa for downstate, and two divs info1 and info2 with the text.

Answer (score 2):

this code may help you

```
   <style>
    .active
    {
        box-shadow: 3px 2px 0px #888888;
    }
</style>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.button').click(function () {

            $(".button").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");

        });
    });</script>
<body>
    <input class="button" type="button" value="1st button" />
    <input class="button" type="button" value="2nd button" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using JQuery, you might as well take advantage of more of its abilities.

**Here's a working example**: http://jsfiddle.net/rrKDd/1/

You can use jquery ui class for disabled style if you have it available:

```
<script>
    var $button1 = $('#myButton'),
        $button2 = $('#myButton2'),
        $text1 = $('#info1'),
        $text2 = $('#info2');

    $button1.click(function () {
        $button1.prop('disabled', true).addClass("ui-state-disabled");
        $text1.show();
        $button2.prop('disabled', false).removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
        $text2.hide();
    });

    $button2.click(function () {
        $button2.prop('disabled', true).addClass("ui-state-disabled");
        $text2.show();
        $button1.prop('disabled', false).removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
        $text1.hide();
    });
</script>
```

You can obviously **choose your own CSS class to add/remove**, and if you don't want them to appear disabled you can just do this:

```
<script>
    var $button1 = $('#myButton'),
        $button2 = $('#myButton2'),
        $text1 = $('#info1'),
        $text2 = $('#info2');

    $button1.click(function () {
        $button1.prop('disabled', true);
        $text1.show();
        $button2.prop('disabled', false);
        $text2.hide();
    });

    $button2.click(function () {
        $button2.prop('disabled', true);
        $text2.show();
        $button1.prop('disabled', false);
        $text1.hide();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this:

```
$('#myButton').on('mousedown', function () {
    $('#myButton').toggleClass('myButtonActivated',0);
    if($('#myButton').hasClass(myButtonActivated)){
        document.getElementById('info1').css('display','block');
        document.getElementById('info2').css('display','none');
    }else{
        document.getElementById('info1').css('display','none');
        document.getElementById('info2').css('display','block');
    }
})
```